# 'required' validation not working properly using xeditable and angualrjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, x-editable

I am working with AngualarJS and I have a Textbox on which i am implementing xeditable

```
<div id="editableTitle">
                <a href="#"  editable-text="template.title" e-required e-placeholder="Enter Unique Title" e-maxlength="30" onaftersave="updateTitle()">{{template.title}}</a>
            </div>
```

The Controller makes a call to database and saves the title.

My Problem is , when I remove the content from text box ,then it shows "Required Field" validation message which is absolutely correct .... but when I I remove the content from text box and add a space .. then the validation fails and it accepts "BLANK" content... this should not happen and for this case.. it should always show "Required Field" validation message.

Answer (score 0):

angularjs by default trims the contents of the ng-model.. you need to use **ng-trim="false"** on your element

```
<a href="#"  ng-trim="false" editable-text="template.title" e-required e-placeholder="Enter Unique Title" e-maxlength="30" onaftersave="updateTitle()">{{template.title}}</a>
```

Comment: I think OP want the opposite of this.